# How to execute await in console when using puppeteer ndb?

Tags: puppeteer, es6-promise, ndb

I am running ndb to debug my puppeteer scripts.
When I put a breakpoint and use console to make some evaluation on selection such as:

```
h1 = await page.$eval("h1", el => el.innerText);
```

I got as result an Promise

[image]

How can I retrieve the result ?

I tried:

```
await page.$eval("h1", el => el.innerText).then((response) => {
         console.log(response);
    });
```

with no success : got a Promise as well